# Can I make a regex match each character in a class EXACTLY ONCE - even when characters REPEAT in the class?

Tags: java, regex, puzzle, anagram

I am trying to pass a set of tests for finding anagrams with my regex in Java.
Is there a way to make the regex match only if each character from the input String is used exactly once, if one or more of the characters appear more than once in the input?

Given the input string `terror` I need to match `rorret`, but not `rottet`. The first two words share all letters exactly, while the third word has three "t" instead of three "r".

The pattern I am using at the moment is `(?i)^(?!terror)[terror]{6}`.

Here is the method:

```java
    private String baseString;

    public String isAnagram(String candidate) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)^(?!"+baseString+")["+baseString+"]{"+baseString.length()+"}");

        (p.matcher(candidate).matches()) ? return candidate: return "Not an anagram.";
```

I have tried negative lookahead: `^(?!.*?([terror]).*?\1)(?!terror)[terror]{6}`

While that makes sure each character is used at least once, it can't account for duplicate lettes in baseString and candidate.

While I am of course aware this could be solved programmatically, it would be so much nicer to just expand the pattern a little to fit this last condition I need.

Comment: This is an anagram question, and pure regex alone probably won't provide the solution.

Comment: Using `'terror'` as an example, it would be easier to simply sort it's letters to form the array `["e", "o", "r", "r", "r", "t"]` and then do the same for each anagram candidate to see it it equals that array. Alternatively (seemingly more efficient), construct a hash that gives counts of each unique letter in `'terror'`, `{"t"=>1, "e"=>1, "r"=>3, "o"=>1}` and then do the same for each anagram candidate to see if that hash results.

Comment: Alright, thank you, Tim and Cary. I'll give up on the regex for now, heartbroken, and look into constructing a hash... I'm looking for an interesting solution and a chance to learn more about Java, so that seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of true regular expressions, the underlying finite state machine would need ~2ⁱ states (where *i* is the number of letters in your string, assuming they're all distinct); it needs to keep track of whether or not it's seen each of the letters, for a storage of *i* bits.

However, I can't see how one would write this in the regular expression syntax; it's probably better to be inspired by it, but implement it manually. With no repeats in the search string, it would be possible to scan the text just once (as a true regular expression would); I can't see how to generalise it to a search string with repeated letters, though.

Comment: Hey @sabik,
thank you for your input. While performance is not an issue for my use case, it's of course always valuable to think about the actual work being done by the machine.
I also like what you said about being "inspired" by the regex, but not using it, I'll probably go that way.
Still, a pity about the pattern... :P